# DropboxSDK and Dropbox framework in iOS

Tags: ios, frameworks, dropbox

I want to use 2 different framework in my project. The frameworks are DropboxSDK.framework and Dropbox.framework. But 2-3 files are common in both these framework which are not allowing me run the application and are giving linker error as following.

```
duplicate symbol _kDBDropboxAPIVersion in:
    /Users/sanchit/Documents/Documents/Projects/VoicePrompt/VoicePrompt 2/DropboxSDK.framework/DropboxSDK
    /Users/sanchit/Documents/Documents/Projects/VoicePrompt/VoicePrompt 2/Dropbox.framework/Dropbox(DBConstants.o)
duplicate symbol _kDBDropboxAPIHost in:
    /Users/sanchit/Documents/Documents/Projects/VoicePrompt/VoicePrompt 2/DropboxSDK.framework/DropboxSDK
    /Users/sanchit/Documents/Documents/Projects/VoicePrompt/VoicePrompt 2/Dropbox.framework/Dropbox(DBConstants.o)
duplicate symbol _kDBDropboxAPIContentHost in:
    /Users/sanchit/Documents/Documents/Projects/VoicePrompt/VoicePrompt 2/DropboxSDK.framework/DropboxSDK
    /Users/sanchit/Documents/Documents/Projects/VoicePrompt/VoicePrompt 2/Dropbox.framework/Dropbox(DBConstants.o)
duplicate symbol _kDBDropboxWebHost in:
    /Users/sanchit/Documents/Documents/Projects/VoicePrompt/VoicePrompt 2/DropboxSDK.framework/DropboxSDK
    /Users/sanchit/Documents/Documents/Projects/VoicePrompt/VoicePrompt 2/Dropbox.framework/Dropbox(DBConstants.o)
duplicate symbol _kDBSDKVersion in:
    /Users/sanchit/Documents/Documents/Projects/VoicePrompt/VoicePrompt 2/DropboxSDK.framework/DropboxSDK
    /Users/sanchit/Documents/Documents/Projects/VoicePrompt/VoicePrompt 2/Dropbox.framework/Dropbox(DBConstants.o)
duplicate symbol _DBErrorDomain in:
    /Users/sanchit/Documents/Documents/Projects/VoicePrompt/VoicePrompt 2/DropboxSDK.framework/DropboxSDK
    /Users/sanchit/Documents/Documents/Projects/VoicePrompt/VoicePrompt 2/Dropbox.framework/Dropbox(DBError.o)
ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have to use both of these framework for different reasons. One framework is not sufficient to do all the things. Is there any way by which I can achieve my target. Please advise.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not answering the question, but I'm curious why you need to use the Core API. (Why isn't the Sync API sufficient?)

Comment: Actually I need to upload videos and also list the only text files in my project. So I am using Datastore API for listing text files and downloading them and Core API for uploading videos.

Comment: Right, but why aren't you using the Sync API for uploading videos?

Comment: Actually I didn't know about Sync API that time when I created the project. So used only Core API for this. Could you please show me an example of sync API for uploading files? Thanks

Comment: Paraphrased from https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/ios#files: `DBFile *file = [[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] createFile:path error:nil]; [file writeString:@"Hello, World!" error:nil];` In your case, you might prefer [writeContentsOfFile](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/ios#DBFile.writeContentsOfFile:shouldSteal:error:).

Comment: yes sir , please provide solution i am also face same problem. i want to marge two framework of dropbox first is dropbox.framework amd 2 is dropboxsdk.framework .but when i am include both in same project then it is giving error about duplicate files in both framework

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue with following files

```
DBAccountInfo

DBConnectController

DBError

DBKeychain

DBSession+iOS

DBSession
```

I have suffixed "Old" to these class names my problem is solved

```
DBAccountInfoOld

DBConnectControllerOld

DBErrorOld

DBKeychainOld

DBSessionOld+iOS

DBSessionOld
```

Comment: Did you also altered the code within these files? Also There are some file which are not there in my framwork. Such as DBConnectController

Comment: If you can give you email id i'll mail dropbox sdk to you

Comment: Could you please send me the modified frameworks to me at sanchit.paurush@mail.vinove.com? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the email. Yes I have received the same at my end. I tried to implement the same in the project. But still it is not working, not  sure why but I am still getting the same error. Are you using any other way to implement this? Please advise. Thanks alot

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40706/discussion-between-pratyusha-terli-and-sanchitsingh)

Comment: Which version are you using? My version of dropbox sdk deos not have DBConstants class

Comment: I am using Core API and Datastore API of dropbox